# Seeking ping equivalent for port 3306

Tags: mysql

Is there a simple ping- like command to test if MySQL's 3306 is responsive?

The ultimate goal is to diagnose [MySQL Workbench: Diagnosing connection error](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/334377/139625)

## NMAP

Assume that MYSQL is on the LAN at a known IP address: 192.168.8.112

```
nmap -p 3306 192.168.8.112
```

returns:

```
Starting Nmap 7.94 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2023-12-27 17:11 EST
Nmap scan report for mysql.local (192.168.8.112)
Host is up (0.0016s latency).

PORT     STATE  SERVICE
3306/tcp closed mysql

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.03 seconds
```

## mysql command line

The mysql command line:

mysql> `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'PORT';`

returns:

```
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| port          | 3306  |
+---------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
```

The ability to 'ping' port 3306 may enable [trouble shooting a connection from MacOS to Ubuntu MySQL with MySQL workbench](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/334377/mysql-workbench-diagnosing-connection-error).

## TELNET

BEFORE binding to 0.0.0.0 was performed:

user@iMac ~ % `telnet 192.168.8.112 3306`
returns:

```
Trying 192.168.8.112...
telnet: connect to address 192.168.8.112: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

After binding was performed:

[image]

## NETSTAT (RECOMMENDED COMMAND)

performed from command mysql host's Ubuntu command line:

```
sudo netstat -tulpn  | grep -e "192.168.8.112" -e "mysql"
```

after [changing the bind-address](https://tecadmin.net/mysql-allow-remote-connections/#) to 0.0.0.0:

[image]

The output indicates MySQL is now listening on 0 0.0.0.0:3306 local address. It means the server is now listening on all network interfaces on port 3306.

reference: https://tecadmin.net/mysql-allow-remote-connections/#

Comment: `SELECT 1`; is 'shorter'.  What is the purpose of your pinging?

Comment: @RickJames ping is a good "smoke test" that confirms a target is 1) listening and 2) active.   The goal is to determine if mySQL is responsive on 3306

Comment: @RickJames.  I posted telnet results at the tail of the posting.  Not sure that it confirms that port 3306 is open and responds via mySQL

Comment: So, none of these commands suits you and you're looking for another one? What exactly should it do that these don't?

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [mysqladmin](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqladmin.html) with the ping option

From the MySQL 5.7 Documentation

> ping
>
> - Check whether the server is available. The return status from mysqladmin is 0 if the server is running, 1 if it is not. This is 0 even in case of an error such as Access denied, because this means that the server is running but refused the connection, which is different from the server not running.

### EXAMPLE #1

Using standing MySQL Connection

```
MYSQL_HOST=...
MYSQL_USER=...
MYSQL_PASS=...
MYSQL_AUTH="-h${MYSQL_HOST} -u${MYSQL_USER} -p${MYSQL_PASS}"
mysqladmin ${MYSQL_AUTH} ping
```

### EXAMPLE #2

Using TCP/IP you could also do

```
MYSQL_HOST=127.0.0.1
MYSQL_PORT=3306
MYSQL_USER=...
MYSQL_PASS=...
MYSQL_AUTH="-h${MYSQL_HOST} -u${MYSQL_USER} -p${MYSQL_PASS}"
MYSQL_AUTH="${MYSQL_AUTH} -P${MYSQL_PORT} --protocol=tcp"
mysqladmin ${MYSQL_AUTH} ping
```

The output will say `mysqld is alive` if you connected successfully. Otherwise, it will give an error message.

You could search for the string `mysqld is alive` as follows

```
MYSQL_HOST=...
MYSQL_USER=...
MYSQL_PASS=...
MYSQL_AUTH="-h${MYSQL_HOST} -u${MYSQL_USER} -p${MYSQL_PASS}"
MYSQL_RUNNING=$(mysqladmin ${MYSQL_AUTH} ping 2>&1 | grep -c "mysqld is alive")
MYSQLD_STATE=Running
[ ${MYSQL_RUNNING} -eq 0 ] && MYSQLD_STATE="Not Running"
echo "mysqld is ${MYSQLD_STATE}"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
telnet hostname 3306
```

is another way.  But it returns an indication that mysqld is responding, plus gibberish (such as asking for a password) that you should ignore.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I posted the results at the tail of the OP.  Not sure if `Connection refuse` confirms an active listening?

Comment: "Connection refused" indicates that nothing is listening. And that corresponds with nmap telling you that port 3306 is closed.

Comment: @DougDeden.  Indeed.   I have changed the MySQL binding from localhost to 0.0.0.0 and posted the new telnet output to confirm your diagnosis

Answer (score 1):

Telnet (like in [Rick's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/334380/170408)) is what I typically use. But I often find myself on a machine that has no telnet client. So the next tool on my list is PowerShell's [test-netconnection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/test-netconnection?view=windowsserver2022-ps) command. It goes something like this:

> test-netconnection < hostname > -port < portnum >

So in your case:

> test-netconnection 192.168.8.112 -port 3306

Comment: Is said command supposed to be in this powershell?  [`brew install --cask powershell`](https://formulae.brew.sh/cask/powershell)

Comment: I'm not familiar with that flavor of PowerShell. I was thinking about the flavor that is built in to Windows. But from some of your updates I see that you aren't running Windows, so PowerShell is not a very helpful answer for you. Sorry.