# MySQL Workbench: Diagnosing connection error

Tags: mysql

MySQL was installed on Ubuntu 22.04 server per instructions on 192.168.8.112:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-22-04

- I am able to SSH into the server and then login into mySQL as root.

The goal is to connect MySQL (MacOS) to MySQL: both server and Mac are on the same LAN.

[image]

"Test Connection" returns:

[image]

## QUESTION

How to diagnose the reason(s) for the error message?

Is workbench configured to **not** use SSH by using port 3306? Why is it trying SSH port 22?
Is there a list of diagnostics that can be performed, so as to ensure that the workbench connects?

Answer (score 0):

Reference: https://tecadmin.net/mysql-allow-remote-connections/#

K**EY FACT:** By default, MySQL is configured to listen on the localhost (127.0.0.1), which means that (initially) it can only be accessed from the same machine it is installed on.   For remote access (MySQL workbench) MySQL must be configured to on other interfaces.

To configure 22.04 to listen from other interfaces: configure MySQL to bind to all interfaces (listen to 0.0.0.0).   In Ubuntu:

```
sudo vi /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
```

set: `bind-address            = 0.0.0.0`

reboot mysql service:

```
systemctl restart mysql.service  #restart
```

[Verify with **netstat**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/334374/139625):

```
sudo netstat -tulpn  | grep -e "192.168.8.112" -e "mysql"
```

[image]